# How do I create an AR marker for Vuforia / Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

This is a horribly basic question I know (!) but how do I create and import an AR marker into Unity? I know I am meant to do it through the Vuforia Marker Manager page. I have created a Target Database and I have downloaded the database, but how do I get the marker to display in Unity?

Also: what exactly is a Target Database? Is that another name for 'marker'?

Comment: I would just use this ... https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21088 notice the video demo

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer your question specifically, yes your Marker is your Target.

So what you need to do is:

- Go to [**License Manager**](https://developer.vuforia.com/license-manager). `Add a License Key` choosing None as your License plan.
- Now go to [**Target Manager**](https://developer.vuforia.com/target-manager). Create a `Database` and add the license for it from the drop down.
- Add Target, and select from your computer the Image that you want to be the Marker, and upload it.
- Once the status of the Target changes to active you can click Download Database and make sure you click For UnityEditor. This downloads a `.unitypackage`
- Now inside Unity, go to `Assets`>`Import New Assets...` and locate to the `.unitypackage` you downloaded

This is how you import your database.

> If you haven't Imported the Vuforia package Unity Extension then you
>   simply need to download it from the [**Downloads**](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk) section and Import it
>   through the `Assets`>`Import Package`> `Custom Package`

- Now ideally to work with AR, you would use the `AR Camera`, which is located in your `Assets` Bar in `Qualcomm Augmented Reality`>`Prefabs`. Drag `ARCamera` onto your scene.
- With the `AR Camera` selected in the `Hierarchy` look at the `Inspector` tab. You'll see `Data Set Load Behavior`. Under that you SHOULD see the name of the `.unitypakage` you imported ealier. Check the name as well as make it `Active`.
- Now in `Qualcomm Augmented Reality`>`Prefabs` you should also see `Image Target`. Drag that onto the screen as well.
- With the `ImageTarget` selected in `Hierarchy` look at the `Inspector`there should be `Image Target Behaviour`

Fill in as follows

```
Type: Predefined
Data Set: <Name of imported .unitypackage>
Image Target: <Name of Picture uploaded into the Database>
```

Now you may work around the Image Target as per your app requirement.

> NOTE: In the License Manager, click on the Name of the License and
>   you'll see a Alpha-numeric code. Copy that code, and within the
>   Inspector of the `AR Camera`, under `QCAR Behaviour>App License Key`
>   paste the code in. This must be done in order for your app to work on your > device.

Hope this helps you. Please feel free to ask me if anything.

Comment: Thanks so, so much for your indepth answer! Managed to get this working with your help.

Comment: Glad to hear it :) I personally struggled with Vuforia. Doesn't have to be like that for everybody! :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple things that you need to do before getting this to work.

Firstly, I noticed you mentioned creating a Target Database on the Vuforia website, but have you actually added any markers to it? Markers are the actual AR images that will be scanned. A Target Database is a collection of markers that can be used simultaneously in your Unity application.

Once you have your markers uploaded they should have a 2-4 star rating as shown in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAgQa.jpg)

After downloading the database as a UnityPackage you have to import it into Unity along with the [Vuforia Unity SDK](https://developer.vuforia.com/downloads/sdk).

If you are still having trouble getting an example scene running within Unity you can download a sample scene at the previous link.