# AR application - 3b object not shown on asus tablet

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

I created an AR application on unity3d using vuforia extension. It runs on unity editor and Samsung Galaxy S3. But when I run it on Asus TF300TG tablet, I don't see 3d object. It don't find marker region. But why? What should I do to find it?

My settings :

[image]

[image]

**EDIT :** 
I get an error message. Unity says that

> Failed to get device caps (0xc0110001) .

Comment: Please take a screenshot of what you've done. What do you mean by `don't find marker region` ?

Comment: My application has a 2d marker image. When it detect the marker on live camera view, it shows 3d object on the marker. I see live camera view , but  not 3d object. So I think that it cannot detect the marker.

Answer (score 0):

Well, from your question, it is unclear of the steps you've taken to get your output. But here's [**an answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29876928/how-do-i-create-an-ar-marker-for-vuforia-unity) that explains the complete guide to getting a simple application working using Vuforia's Unity Extension.

But specifically, make sure with the `AR Camera` you've set `Data Set Load Behavior`. Under that you SHOULD see the name of the `.unitypakage` you imported. Check the name as well as make it `Active`.

Also, regarding the `Image Target Behavior` should be `Predefined` and the package name and Image name must be selected.

For more details please refer the link above. Good luck. :)

Comment: Thanks your help. But I know these step. My application works properly unity editor and my smart phone. But it doesn't find marker and show 3d object on my tablet.

Comment: If doesn't find the marker then you've not activated the Dataset either in the ARCamera or the ImageTarget. Please upload screenshots of your setup otherwise. :)